# PDF viewer with "Image copy" function similar to that of TeXShop

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

The MacOS app TeXShop has a PDF viewer that has a very powerful function. You can select any rectangle in a PDF document and then copy/paste or drag/drop it somewhere. It creates a PDF file of this part of the document. (you can choose other formats in the settings as well) Importantly, it preserves it as a vector image if the original PDF is vector.

Is there any other PDF viewer that has a similar function? Ideally a one that also runs on Linux?